# elasticsearch nested aggregation is empty

Tags: elasticsearch, nested

So, I have an index in Elasticsearch 7.6, which has documents similar to this one:

```
{
  "_index": "my-index",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "kjdskjwolsjj",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "timestamp": "2018-04-22T20:11:35.0292586Z",
    "batchId": "9c96d360-5549-4b3b-85c8-756330117bad",
    "userId": "id-001-001",
    "things": [
      {
        "id": 650055867,
        "name": "green",
      },
      {
        "id": 523,
        "name": "eggs",
      },
      {
        "id": 1269,
        "name": "ham",
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Of course, this is just one document of many in the index.  I would like to create an aggregate bucket of all the "things" in my index, so that I could sub aggregate against that bucket.

My agg query looks like this:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "all_things": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "_source.things"
       }
     }
   }
}
```

(BTW ... if I used just "things" as the nested path, it complains "[nested] nested path [things] is not nested".)

Finally the result (using the Kibana console) is:

```
{
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1408,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "all_things" : {
      "doc_count" : 0
    }
  }
}
```

Could someone explain why I get no docs in my bucket?  Or perhaps a decent way to create a bucket of all my "things"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've gotta index your `things` as [`nested`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html):

```
PUT my-index
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "things": {
        "type": "nested"
      }
    }
  }
}

POST my-index/_doc
{
  "timestamp": "2018-04-22T20:11:35.0292586Z",
  "batchId": "9c96d360-5549-4b3b-85c8-756330117bad",
  "userId": "id-001-001",
  "things": [
    {
      "id": 650055867,
      "name": "green"
    },
    {
      "id": 523,
      "name": "eggs"
    },
    {
      "id": 1269,
      "name": "ham"
    }
  ]
}
```

Then and only then will your nested aggs work:

```
GET my-index/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "things_ids": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "things"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "things_ids": {
          "cardinality": {
            "field": "things.id"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If I add this mapping to my index, which already contains documents, will the "nested" property be applied to those current docs too?

Comment: to answer my own question... i had to re-index to get the nested property to work.